# I'm getting a list of lists that each have one tuple. How do I get one list with several tuples?

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples, list-comprehension

I need to create 1 list that has several tuples in it. All I can use is randint.

I have this:

```
import random

first_names = ['chris', 'joe', 'billie', 'rose', 'nathatn']
names = []

counter = 0
for name in first_names:
    counter += 1
    names = [(counter , first_names[random.randint(0, len(first_names)-1)])  ] 
    print(names)
```

I get a result like this:

```
[(1, 'chris')]
[(2, 'nathatn')]
[(3, 'billie')]
[(4, 'joe')]
[(5, 'chris')]
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is a list like this:

```
[(1, 'chris'), (2, 'nathan'), (3, 'billie'), (4, 'joe'), (5, 'chris')]
```

I can accomplish this format by using:

```
names = [(first_names[random.randint(0, len(first_names)-1)],\
last_names[random.randint(0, len(last_names)-1)]) for name in range(0, len(first_names))]
```

But I can't figure out how to get the counter to work in that list comprehension. When I add 'counter' as the first part of the tuple, it just gives me 5 for every tuple. I need 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. When I add 'counter +=1' as the first part of the tuple, I get a syntax error.

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list comprehension is completely fine. The problem is that you're replacing the names list every time you iterate through the for loop. You need to use the list.append() feature and tuple comprehension. Also, to get a single list with all the elements your print statement should be outside of the for loop. Something like:

```
import random

first_names = ['chris', 'joe', 'billie', 'rose', 'nathatn']
names = []

counter = 0
for name in first_names:
    counter += 1
    t = (counter , first_names[random.randint(0, len(first_names)-1)]) 
    names.append(t)
print(names)
```

will get you what you need.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
import random

first_names = ['chris', 'joe', 'billie', 'rose', 'nathatn']
names = []


for name in first_names:
    te=random.choice(first_names)
    names.append(te)
    print(names)
print(list(enumerate(names,1)))
```

you can use `random.choice()`

```
random.choice(seq):Return a random element from the non-empty sequence seq.
```

you can use `enumerate` to generate your `counter` variable automatically

```
Output:
[(1, 'rose'), (2, 'joe'), (3, 'billie'), (4, 'nathatn'), (5, 'joe')]
```

If you need a list without elements in list being repeated you can use
`random.sample)`

```
random.sample(population, k, *, counts=None)
Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence or set. Used for random sampling without replacement.sample(['red', 'blue'], counts=[4, 2], k=5) is equivalent to sample(['red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue'], k=5).

list(enumerate(random.sample(first_names,5)))
[(0, 'billie'), (1, 'nathatn'), (2, 'joe'), (3, 'rose'), (4, 'chris')]
```

As you can see `enumerate` starts with `0`. but you can change that

```
list(enumerate(random.sample(first_names,5),1))
[(1, 'rose'), (2, 'billie'), (3, 'joe'), (4, 'nathatn'), (5, 'chris')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random
random.shuffle(first_names) # shuffle list first_names
list(enumerate(first_names, 1)) # add index into the element
```